# How to find the approximation of a polynomial function up to n decimal place accuracy using Taylor series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Suppose, $f(x)=2x^3+7x^2+x-1$ is a polynomial of degree 3. If I were to expand the function about $x=2$ and approximate that up to 5 decimal place accuracy, how do I approach? (This came in my exam, no interval was given)

I have tried the following approach:
Expanding up to 2nd degree: $45+\left(x-2\right)\cdot53+\frac{\left(x-2\right)^{2}}{2!}\cdot38$
Expanding up to 3rd degree: $45+\left(x-2\right)\cdot53+\frac{\left(x-2\right)^{2}}{2!}\cdot38+\frac{\left(x-2\right)^{3}}{3!}\cdot12$
The last one is the exact same equation given in the question. But the second one does not ensure 5 decimal place accuracy. How do I find the region where the expansion is correct up to the given accuracy?

Comment: The question is unclear, what do we have to approximate up to a given error $\epsilon$? We can and will compute $f(2)$ exactly. If the question is to find a disk $D$ around $2$ so that for all $x\in D$ we have $|f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$, then this is a completely different question.

Comment: @dan_fulea If that would have been the case, how do I go for it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder We need the remainder w.r.t. the constant Taylor polynomial